# issue with list error in python class

Tags: python, class, oop

[Class intSet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7TTw.png)

I'm trying to understand the following code from the MIT python class. When i create an object of the class intSet as follows i run into some trouble with one of the attributes.

```
s=intSet()
```

and try

```
s.vals()
```

I get the following error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    s.vals()
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

why is this? I've been told i shouldn't try s.vals directly because of data hiding, when i try s.vals the correct list is returned but i get an error when trying s.vals(). Can someone explain this error? I'm new to both OOP and python so i apologise for my poor questioning. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why the parentheses?

Comment: Please post all code here, as text.

Comment: What do you expect that adding the parentheses does? Parentheses try to use the attribute like a function, i.e., it tries to call the attribute like a function. As the error states, `s.vals` is a *list*, which isn't callable.

Comment: BTW, while that is a great course, it unfortunately does not stick to typical python conventions. If you want an attribute to be "private", pre-pend an underscore, `self._vals = []`. This is privacy by convention, no one is actually prevented from accessing your attribute. But people who use your code base know "this is an implementation detail and not a guarantee, don't use this, and if you do, know you can't rely on this behavior". Also, Python generally is written using "snake_case" instead of "camelCase".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'd upvote you (+10 rep) if I could. I never knew it was called snake_case. I always referred to it as c_case or underscore_case.

Comment: Also, typically instead of writing getters and setters, which is the common way to use data-hiding/encapuslation, in Python, you would use [properties](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php). This is for more intermediate/advanced Python programming. Stick to whatever your course is using, though.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ heh, I find it particularly pleasant because snake -> python :)

Comment: Beautiful... so... beautiful...

Answer (score 2):

vals is not a method it is an attribute so you can't call it. In python the parentheses indicate you are calling a method. So just do `s.vals`

Comment: Great to hear. If you could up vote and/or accept that would be awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use s.vals() it tries to call function 'vals' through variable 's' whereas, when you use s.vals it doesnt look for the function just returns the value stored in s.vals.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `vals` that is a list. You are doing something like this `[]()`, that is not possible.

What you should do in OOP way is to declare getter function like that:

```
class intSet(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__vals = [] # kinda private class instance
        # .... other code


    @property
    def vals(self):
        return self.__vals

intset = intSet()
intset.vals # is that list
```

More info [about private members in python](http://radek.io/2011/07/21/private-protected-and-public-in-python/) and [about properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)

Comment: do *not* use double-underscore name-mangling. This is not the purpose of it, use a *single underscore*.

Comment: I know that :-) The single underscore does not create the masking of name, in fact. If you put single `_`, it seems like _protected_ member in terms of OOP languages. The true way of _private_ member is to make it double-underscored.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is right. That's not what double-underscore name-mangling is suppose to be used for. In short, it's used to avoid naming-conflicts among child classes. Along with that, there really is no reason for `self.vals` to be private. have getters and setters simply out of convention in Python is generally frowned upon.

Comment: No, this is shoe-horning Java/C++ ideas about access modifiers into a language that simply does not support them. What you are saying in the Python world with double-underscore name-mangling is "let this name be used by subclasses without shadowing the parent attribute". Python is not Java. Don't write Python like Java.

Comment: @ChristianDean exactly! The *whole point* of having properties is that you *don't write them unless you need them*. If you write a property that simply does `return self._attribute`, then you likely don't need it in the first place. Just use `self.attribute`. If you need to change the way `self.attribute` is accessed/set at some later point, *then use the property*. That is the *beauty of properties*, we don't have to write stupid getter/setter boilerplate. See [this](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php) tutorial.

Comment: Everyone does single underscore in Python, and so do I. It's normal. It is an example of _true_ private class member in classic style. The python implementation of concept in classic OOP, that is not Python OOP, it's slightly different.

Comment: I'm talking about double-underscore name-mangling. This does not make it "truly private", such a thing does *NOT* exist in Python. You can approximate it using a lot of metaclass magic, but even then it is usually easily circumventable. "private, public, protected" are not concepts in Python.

Comment: Me too, in fact. My point of double-underscore was that it really hides values. Mostly, yeah, it is bullshit to do such thing. But it is an _example_ of how you can implement _true private_ class members in Python

Comment: No, it is **not truly private**. It is *name-mangling*. That is it's whole purpose.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it was a terminology misunderstanding. Yeah, it does _name-mengling_. It is a hacky way, but it allows to hide variables so noone to acces it by original name